# How can I resolve libmysql with Percona now that they've caused a yum conflict with their packages?

Tags: php, percona

A script I wrote a few months ago has provisioned probably 100 or more virtual servers with a LAPP stack (Linux Apache Percona PHP).

Recently, the following line is failing because yum has Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-devel marked as a conflict against Percona-Server-client-55, which means you can't yum install libmysqlclient_r which is a dependency for PHP to build.

```
rpm -Uhv http://www.percona.com/downloads/percona-release/percona-release-0.0-1.x86_64.rpm 2>&1 >> $logfile; yum install Percona-Server-client-55 Percona-Server-server-55 percona-toolkit.noarch Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-devel -y
```

... stuff happens then:

```
Error: Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-devel-55 conflicts with Percona-Server-client-55-5.5.37-rel35.0.el6.x86_64
```

Because of this, I can't compile PHP:

```
checking for mysql_close in -lmysqlclient_r... no
checking for mysql_error in -lmysqlclient_r... no
configure: error: mysql configure failed. Please check config.log for more information.
```

I can't possibly be the only person trying to compile PHP from source, does anyone know of a way of installing libmysqlclient_r through Percona?

Answer (score 4):

Well shame on me, I was able to install Percona Shared Compat to get rid of this issue:

Percona-Server-shared-compat.x86_64

I hope this helps others.

Comment: Percona-Server-devel-55-5.5.37-rel35.0.el6.x86_64 may be worth mentioning as well, as it includes headers and such.

Comment: I tried installing Percona-Server-shared-compat, but I am getting this:
"error: Failed dependencies: mariadb-libs is obsoleted by Percona-Server-shared-compat-57-5.7.10-1rc1.1.el7.x86_64 "

Comment: It sounds like you may already have a conflicting package installed. Are you currently using MariaDB? If so, you may wish to just use Maria instead of percona. 

If this isn't your intention, and you don't have Mariadb running a production database, you'll need to fully remove MariaDB to install Percona. 

You could do that with:
yum remove mariadb*

Please make sure to make any appropriate DB backups before hand if your mariadb installation has data in it.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am running mariadb. I ended up removing the Pecona server package, kept mariadb-server and installed mariadb-devel package without issue.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it resolved